# Word / idiom meaning things you had to have seen live

Tags: slang, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

In the [*viewing party*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1752582/?ref_=ttep_ep8) episode of [*The Office (US)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386676/), office worker [*Jim*   describes](http://www.officequotes.net/no7-08.php) some special events which are broadcast live on television as:

> Some events are so news worthy, so historic, that you have to stop everything to watch. Balloon Boy, Michael Jackson's funeral. *Things that if you didn't see them live, you wouldn't really care that you didn't see them at all.*

There are of course phrases to indicate they you only get a joke or statement when you were at a certain event, for example the phrase [*had to be there*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Had%20to%20be%20there). This phrase, however, excludes those who saw events as they unfolded on television, I am looking for a phrase which includes those people.

To put it more generally, I am looking for a phrase or idiom, possibly slang, to later describe a situation you should have seen live (either by having witnessed the event(s) in real-life or by having seen it unfold as they happened on television) to fully understand a statement, joke or feeling?

Can you come up with such a phrase or idiom? I get that the description in the popular-culture quote slightly differs from how I phrased it, however, I would point out that any answer which captures the sentiment of *having to have followed it live, in real time* is within the scope of this question.

Comment: See-it-to-believe-it. As in "It was a see-it-the-believe-it moment/ episode, when he peed in his pants during police investigation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

"Had to have been there".
"Should have been there".
"Heat of the moment"?
"Once in a lifetime"

Answer (score 0):

**believe it when (I,we) see it**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27ll+believe+it+when+I+see+it)

> I highly doubt that could happen or is the case. The phrase implies
>   that one would need to witness or see proof of such a thing to believe
>   it.

Comment: I'd like to think you were right…